# Reactive extensions delayed initialization

Tags: c#, system.reactive, simple-injector

It's fairly established that doing work in ctors for types that are resolved using SimpleInjector is bad practice. Although this often leads to certain late initializations of such types, a particularly interesting case is Reactive Extensions subscriptions.

Take for instance an observable sequence that exhibits `Replay(1)` semantics (actually `BehaviorSubject` if we take the `StartWith` into account), e.g.

```
private readonly IObservable<Value> _myObservable;

public MyType(IService service)
{
    _myObservable = service.OtherObservable
        .StartWith(service.Value)
        .Select(x => SomeTransform())
        .Replay(1)
        .RefCount();
}

public IObservable<Value> MyObservable => _myObservable;
```

Assume now, that `SomeTransform` is computationally expensive. From the point of view of SimpleInjector, the above is bad practice. Ok, so we need some kind of `Initialize()` method to call after SimpleInjector is finished. But what about our replay semantics and our `StartWith()`? Our consumers expect a value when they `Subscribe` (assume now that this is guaranteed to happen after initialization)!

How do we get around these restrictions in a nice way while still satisfying SimpleInjector? Here's a summary of requirements:

1. Don't do extensive work in the ctor (i.e. `SomeTransform`) should not run
2. `_myObservable` should be `readonly`
3. `MyObservable` should exhibit `Replay(1)` semantics
4. We should always have an initial value (hence the `StartWith`)
5. We do not want to `Subscribe` inside `MyType` and cache the value (we like immutability)

I experimented with creating an additional observable that starts with `false` and then gets set to `true` on initialize, and then merging that together with `_myObservable`, but couldn't quite get it to work. Additionally, it doesn't seem like the best solution. In essence, all I want to do is delay until `Initialize()` is done. There must be some way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `SomeTransform();` is not called during the constructor. It is used when someone is actually using the `MyObservable` property.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Reactive Extensions,but will `SomeTransform()` actually be invoked from within the constructor, or does that only happen when that other service pushes a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection constructors should be [simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and [reliable](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/). This means that the following practices are frowned upon:

- Doing any I/O operations inside the constructor. I/O operations can fail and make construction of the object graph unreliable.
- Using the class's dependencies inside the constructor. Not only could a called dependency cause I/O of its own, sometimes injected dependencies are not (yet) fully initialized, and final initialization happens at a later point in time. Perhaps after the object graph has been constructed.

Considering how Reactive Extensions work, your `MyType` constructor doesn't seem to do any I/O. Its `SomeTransform` method is not called during the creation of `MyType`. Instead, the observable is configured to call `SomeTransform` when objects are pushed. This means that from a DI perspective, your injection is still 'simple' and fast. Sometimes your classes need some initialization on top of storing incoming dependencies. Creating and storing a `Lazy<T>`, for instance, is a good example. It allows delaying doing some I/O while still having more code than merely "receiving the dependencies."

But still you are accessing a dependency inside your constructor, which might cause trouble if that dependency, or its dependencies are not fully initialized. Further more, with Reactive Extensions you make a runtime dependency from `IService` back to `MyType` (you already have a design-time dependency from `MyType` to `IService`). This is very similar to working with events in .NET. Consequence of this is that it could cause `MyType` to be kept alive by `IService`, even when `MyType` lifetime is expected to be shorter.

So, strictly spoken, from a DI perspective this configuration might be troublesome. But it's hard to imagine a different model when working with Reactive Extensions. That would mean you have to move this configuration of the observables out of the constructors, and do it after the object graph has been constructed. But that will likely cause having to open up your classes so the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) has access to the methods that need to be called. It also causes [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

In other words, when using Reactive Extensions, it is probably good to have some design rules in place to prevent trouble. These rules could be:

- All exposed `IObservable<T>` properties should always be fully initialized and usable after its type's construction.
- All observers and observables should have the same lifetime.

Comment: (1) After thinking about this for some time myself, I fully agree with your take on this. I think the major problem with my original setup was the `StartWith()`. This, in and of itself, will cause `SomeTransform()` to run during construction, which would be bad. I've concluded that, when combing DI with RX, we should never create an observable with `Replay` semantics if the the initial value requires computation.

Comment: (2) Moreover, it's also better if the observable created in the constructor is not subscribed to in the constructor. The act of subscribing may itself trigger a computation because the consumed stream may immediately emit a value, and we cannot have that happen in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution that comes to mind is the use of [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netcore-3.1)

This could look like:

```
private readonly Lazy<IObservable<Value>> _lazyMyObservable;

public MyType(IService service)
{
    _lazyMyObservable =  new Lazy<IObservable<Value>>(() => this.InitObservable(service));
}

private IObservable<Value> InitObservable(IService service)
{
    return service.OtherObservable
        .StartWith(service.Value)
        .Select(x => SomeTransform())
        .Replay(1)
        .RefCount();
 }

 public IObservable<Value> MyObservable => _lazyMyObservable.Value;
```

This will init the variable `_lazyMyObservable` without actually calling `SomeTransform()`. When a consumer asks for `MyType.MyObservable` the `InitObservable` code will be called one time and one time only. This postpones the initialization to the point where the code is actually used.

This will keep your constructor nice and clean and has no need to add initialization logic.

Note that the ctor of the `Lazy<T>` has several overloads that you can use if you may have issues with multithreading.

Comment: Thanks @Ric, this is also a great suggestion.